# How to write a retail scheduler

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Ive gotten mixed reports as to how to handle this question while reviewing the web so I thought I should ask you all. I am not sure if its possible to even do with JavaScript, PHP, and MySql, but here is what I wanna do.

Im a manager at a small retailer where I have to schedule 20 people each week. Each day we have different hours, some people are part time, others full time, etc.

Can I create a webpage that can handle this? I was thinking of making a employee database with their status as FT or PT etc but did not know what language would be best to use for a full out functioning scheduler. Also, Id like to eventually add the option to enter day off requests into the form so that the scheduler would not allow them to work on those requested days.

The scheduler would have to be automated and of course may require some user tweaking after it generates.

I AM NOT LOOKING for the code for this.... just suggestions and thoughts as to where you would start (what language, format, etc)

Comment: everything can be done with `PHP` no reason for your question.

Comment: A web app makes sense if you need a distributed app.  That is, more than one person or computer needs to access and/or update the same data.  If only one person or computer need access to the data, you can save money and complexity by writing a local app.

Comment: I just want to make a local app. I am going to admit that I am very new to this, and am a student at the time. Today at work I had the idea for this because every week I spend an hour writing a schedule. I am doing really good with PHP and MySql so I was figuring that would be the way to go. Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: Choosing a language for something like this would be based almost entirely on personal preference.  Use the language you are most comfortable with or most interested in learning.

Comment: Why don't you get an already available scheduler then? These days one can find many things already in Open Source. Why re-invent the wheel

Comment: There really ISNT anything in open source that can accomplish this already. Its actually pretty complex. I am going to try using PHp once I figure out the logic. There are a LOT of variables and constraints I need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @gilly3 said, the language you use is really up to your personal preference and what knowledge you already have. Here are some overviews of the ones I think would be acceptable:

- **Python** is probably one of the easier languages to learn, mostly because of the way it's so easy to read.

  - There are many great ways to learn it. I like [this nettuts+ series](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/python-from-scratch-creating-a-dynamic-website/). The series is about creating dynamic websites with Django, but before it gets to that, it goes through the python language quite thoroughly. There are also may other sites you can go to to learn about python, such as [python.org](http://www.python.org/doc/) and others.
  - Python works best with creating local applications, not online ones. However, there are ways to use python in web development.
  - You would most likely record peoples stats (part-time, full-time...etc.) in a file, either a python file or another file that could be parsed by python (eg. XML or JSON).
  - For the results, you could have it print something out to the command line/teminal or use the tkinter library. to open a window and display the schedule visually.

---

- **PHP** would be your best choice if you plan to record peoples stats in a MySQL database, maybe with phpMyAdmin or something like it.

  - PHP would need to be hosted on a server (Apache, IIS...etc.), but that shouldn't be a   problem.
  - That too is an extremely easy language to learn, due to the vast amount of resources available, [php.net](http://www.php.net/docs.php) is one of the best places I think, but you may find another that you like better.

---

- If you like **HTML**, **CSS** and **JavaScript**, then you could simply create a webpage and have the user open it in their browser.

  - If you used this option, you would write out the people's stats in a file (probably JSON if you're working with JavaScript or it could be just plain JavaScript), and simply reference it with a `<script>` tag or and Ajax call.
  - There are *so* may resources out there for learning these that I can't even remember my favorites.
  - JavaScript is probably the best if you want the user to be able to edit the schedule right in the program.
- If you like **HTML**, **CSS** and **JavaScript**, but want a desktop application, check out [TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org/)

Keep in mind that if you use PHP and MySQL, you will also have the full power of HTML, CSS and JavaScript in your hands. For that reason, I would recommend PHP. It's only drawback is needing a server, but there are many ways to get around that ([XAMPP (windows/linux)](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), [WAMP (windows)](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), [MAMP (mac)](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) and probably others, but those are the most famous.

Sorry if I've left anything out, feel free to edit.